# How to treat simple edit of the question

Tags: discussion

Many times I have seen a good post, with nothing to change (mostly grammar), but the code is not formatted.
When I try to format the code, I am not allowed to do it, since I must have at least 6 changes. But the only thing I need to change is a simple format.

Currently the only thing I can do is to flag it as "Requires editing".

How should I approach this?

Comment: Do you have an example? I've never seen a post that could not stand at least 6 characters of improvement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an example.

Comment: There was already a discussion about this (but can't find it yet) and the result was: try to find more stuff to fix (like Robert wrote above) or wait until you have 2k reputation.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Now I know what to do :)